# TypeScript: walkthrough: inheretance

Tags: inheritance, typescript

On http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground there is a walkthrough about inheretance. Code a bit modified to be more friendly.

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
    move(meters: number) {
        console.log(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move() {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(5);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move() {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(45);
    }
}

var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");

sam.move();
tom.move(11);
```

second object is animal

```
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");
tom.move(11);
```

Now as C# developer I'd expect to see this kind of result

```
Slithering...
Sammy the Python moved 5m.
Tommy the Palomino moved 11m.
```

so move method from Horse should not be called. How ever I see something different.

```
Slithering...
Sammy the Python moved 5m.
Galloping...
Tommy the Palomino moved 45m.
```

as it seems that it's ignoring the parameter "11" from:

```
tom.move(11);
```

and is running method from derivative class.

Regards to this I have two questions.

1. why this is happening or maybe this is a bug
2. if it's intended behavior how to call method from Animal Class provided I don't want to create Animal Object like this.

   ```
   var tom: Animal = new Animal ("Tommy the Palomino");
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why this is happening or maybe this is a bug?

You are right. This is different in TypeScript.

When doing something like:

```
(new MyClass()).overriddenMethod();
```

it is the method defined in MyClass that will be called no matter what.

This is due to the fact that (in javascript) there is no such thing as overriding a method; it will, in effect, be replaced.

Take the example:

```c
class Animal {
    move(meters: number) { console.log("Moved " + meters + "m."); }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    move() { super.move(5); }
}
```

it compiles to (removed the _extends implementation for simplicity):

```
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal() {
    }
    Animal.prototype.move = function (meters) { console.log("Moved " + meters + "m."); };
    return Animal;
})();
var Snake = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Snake, _super);
    function Snake() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Snake.prototype.move = function () { _super.prototype.move.call(this, 5); };
    return Snake;
})(Animal);
```

the `move` on `Snake` will simply replace the `move` implementation on `Animal`. Internally you can call the parent method utilising `super`, but no conversion to the parent class will ever be made outside of the class.

So the ability to do:

```
var foo: Animal = new Snake("Some awesome snake");
```

Is simply to say that `Snake` has the same "interface" (i.e. it, kinda, looks like an `Animal`) but if you override a method on the parent class you can never get it back, so to speak. The ability to get that kind of polymorphism disappears when transpiling to javascript, where all knowledge of the types are discarded.

> 2. if it's intended behavior how to call method from Animal Class
>      provided I don't want to create Animal Object like this.

You can do something like this:

```
class Animal {
    move(meters: number) { console.log("Moved " + meters + "m."); }
}

class Snake extends Animal {

    move(meters?: number) {
        super.move(meters != null ? meters : 5);
    }
}
```

or even:

```
class Animal {
    move(meters: number) { console.log("Moved " + meters + "m."); }
}

class Snake extends Animal {

    move();
    move(meters: number);
    move(someRandomThing: MyNiceObject);
    move(meters: number, someRandomThing: MyNiceObject);
    move() {
        var args = arguments;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            super.move(3);
        }
        else if (args.length == 2) {
            // Do something related to..
            // move(meters: number, someRandomThing: MyNiceObject);
        }
        else {
            if (typeof(args[0]) === "number") {
                // move(meters: number);
            } else {
                // move(someRandomThing: MyNiceObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So.. from a classical oo approach this might seem limiting (I come from c#, c++ etc my self). But I rarely notice it any more, it still beets pure javascript any day of the week!